# How to toggle Slick slider on click (slide down and slide back up)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm working on trying to get a smooth slide down animation on some Slick sliders.

I need the slider and "projects" button to animate in a slide-down motion upon the above title being clicked.

I have it where the slider/button container does slide down on click (toggling a class that changes the max-height of the container), but the slider and button sort of just pop into view and don't animate down with the container.

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/Finches/pen/jYrzWv

Any help getting a smooth slide down transition here? Code snippet...

```
.service-content-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 2s;
}

.accordion-content-wrapper {
  background: blue;
}

.active {
  max-height: 1000px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

-

```
$('.title-box').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.service-content-wrapper').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: just posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to change a few things if you want to animate the height via css without using `@keyframes` see if below is how you want then slides to appear, try viewing in the full screen.

```js
$('.accordion-content-wrapper').slick({
  prevArrow: false
});

$('.title-box').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.service-content-wrapper').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.title-box h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
}

.service-content-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  /*   margin-bottom: 25px; */
  height: 0px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 1s;
}

.accordion-content-wrapper {
  background: blue;
}

.active {
  transition: 1s;
  height: 350px;
}

.slide-1,
.slide-2 {
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-next {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

.title-box {
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
  position: relative;
}

.service-container {
  /*   background: pink; */
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.page-container {
  padding: 25px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 15px;
  background: salmon;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexboxgrid/6.3.1/flexboxgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="row page-container">

  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 services-column">

    <div class="service-container">

      <div class="title-box col-md-12">
        <h1>HEAVY CIVIL</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="service-content-wrapper">

        <div class="accordion-content-wrapper col-md-12">

          <div class="slide-1 col-md-12">
            This is test content.
          </div>
          <!-- slide-1 -->

          <div class="slide-2 col-md-12">
            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
              here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
            <p> Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes
              by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
          </div>
          <!-- slide-2 -->

        </div>
        <!-- accordion-content-wrapper -->

        <div class="btn col-md-12">PROJECTS</div>

      </div>
      <!-- service-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- service-container -->

    <div class="service-container">

      <div class="title-box col-md-12">
        <h1>HEAVY CIVIL</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="service-content-wrapper">

        <div class="accordion-content-wrapper col-md-12">

          <div class="slide-1 col-md-12">
            This is test content.
          </div>
          <!-- slide-1 -->

          <div class="slide-2 col-md-12">
            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
              here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
            <p> Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes
              by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
          </div>
          <!-- slide-2 -->

        </div>
        <!-- accordion-content-wrapper -->

        <div class="btn col-md-12">PROJECTS</div>

      </div>
      <!-- service-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- service-container -->

  </div>
  <!-- col-md-4 -->

  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 services-column">

    <div class="service-container">

      <div class="title-box col-md-12">
        <h1>HEAVY CIVIL</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="service-content-wrapper">

        <div class="accordion-content-wrapper col-md-12">

          <div class="slide-1 col-md-12">
            This is test content.
          </div>
          <!-- slide-1 -->

          <div class="slide-2 col-md-12">
            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
              here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
            <p> Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes
              by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
          </div>
          <!-- slide-2 -->

        </div>
        <!-- accordion-content-wrapper -->

        <div class="btn col-md-12">PROJECTS</div>

      </div>
      <!-- service-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- service-container -->

    <div class="service-container">

      <div class="title-box col-md-12">
        <h1>HEAVY CIVIL</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="service-content-wrapper">

        <div class="accordion-content-wrapper col-md-12">

          <div class="slide-1 col-md-12">
            This is test content.
          </div>
          <!-- slide-1 -->

          <div class="slide-2 col-md-12">
            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
              here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
            <p> Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes
              by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
          </div>
          <!-- slide-2 -->

        </div>
        <!-- accordion-content-wrapper -->

        <div class="btn col-md-12">PROJECTS</div>

      </div>
      <!-- service-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- service-container -->

  </div>
  <!-- col-md-4 -->

  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 services-column">

    <div class="service-container">

      <div class="title-box col-md-12">
        <h1>HEAVY CIVIL</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="service-content-wrapper">

        <div class="accordion-content-wrapper col-md-12">

          <div class="slide-1 col-md-12">
            This is test content.
          </div>
          <!-- slide-1 -->

          <div class="slide-2 col-md-12">
            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
              here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
            <p> Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes
              by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
          </div>
          <!-- slide-2 -->

        </div>
        <!-- accordion-content-wrapper -->

        <div class="btn col-md-12">PROJECTS</div>

      </div>
      <!-- service-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- service-container -->

    <div class="service-container">

      <div class="title-box col-md-12">
        <h1>HEAVY CIVIL</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="service-content-wrapper">

        <div class="accordion-content-wrapper col-md-12">

          <div class="slide-1 col-md-12">
            This is test content.
          </div>
          <!-- slide-1 -->

          <div class="slide-2 col-md-12">
            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
              here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
            <p> Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes
              by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
          </div>
          <!-- slide-2 -->

        </div>
        <!-- accordion-content-wrapper -->

        <div class="btn col-md-12">PROJECTS</div>

      </div>
      <!-- service-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- service-container -->

  </div>
  <!-- col-md-4 -->

</div>
<!-- row -->
```